# How to write a function in T-SQL, which accepts a table as input and returns result back as a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is the code I used to create a function, which accepts `table` as input and after operation within the function returns result in `table` format as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_CalculateListing(@Listing ListingColumn READONLY)    --(ROWID INT,value1 INT, value2 INT))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(50))

    INSERT INTO @result(ID,Name)
        SELECT ROWID, Name
        FROM @Listing

    RETURN @Listing
END
```

I tried to use `table-inline parameter` but receive the following error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure fn_CalculateListing, Line 16
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@Listring".
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure fn_CalculateListing, Line 29
>   Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.`

How can I make it correct?

Comment: First you must declare a TYPE for the input. Second you are mixing the two flavours of creating a function. One is with BEGIN and END which needs a detailled table declaration, the other one continues with `RETURN SELECT ...` immediately after the `AS`. The first is a "multi-statement TVF` and you should **avoid** it if ever possible. The second is an inlineable (ad-hoc) TVF which is **really great!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is important to specify the `dbo` schema. I'm also defining the `@result` table a bit differently than in your code.

I've checked that the following script works:

**Create table type**

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ListingColumn] AS TABLE(
    [ROWID] [int] NULL,
    [value1] [int] NULL,
    [value2] [int] NULL
)
GO
```

**Create table-valued function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CalculateListing](@Listing dbo.ListingColumn READONLY)
RETURNS @result TABLE
(
    ID INT,
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result(ID, Name)
    SELECT ROWID, value1
    FROM @Listing;

    RETURN;
END
GO
```

If your function can be expressed as a single `SELECT`, it is much better to write it as a single-statement inline user-defined function. The syntax will look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InlineCalculateListing](@Listing dbo.ListingColumn READONLY)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT ROWID, value1
    FROM @Listing AS L
);
GO
```

Comment: You should **absolutely** avoid multi-statement TVFs! Just write `RETURNS TABLE` and (without BEGIN and END!) you continue with `AS RETURN SELECT ...`. Doing so the TVF will be real ad-hoc SQL, will be fully inlineable and **much** better in performance! And it will know its columns automatically. It is - technically spoken - a parameterized VIEW...

Comment: This flavor of TVF (with BEGIN and END) allows you to write many steps, to declare variables, whatever... The price for this is **extremely poor performance**! There are very rare situations where such a TVF would be the right choice...

Comment: @Shnugo, I added a second variant with the correct syntax for inline UDF. You are right, if it is possible to make inline UDF, you should make it such. If not, it is possible to have a multi-statement function, but its performance would be generally worse.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I cannot check it at the moment, but I think you should let away the paranthesis. Just ' RETURN SELECT...` Happy coding!

Comment: @Shnugo, I checked both variants in SSMS before posting an answer. The syntax is correct.